# Parse Rails Production log to get number of times a page is viewed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, cron, heroku

What would be the best way to parse a production log once a night, count how many hits each page got and then increment a hit counter for each page in a database?

Here is an example entry:

```
GET myapp.com/project/11 dyno=web.3 queue=0 wait=0ms service=168ms bytes=26378
```

My app is currently hosted on heroku.

Comment: with all the handy dandy tricks rails provides to wrap functionality already, I would think you should just record the page views as they happen in your application rather than fiddling with the logs after the fact.

Comment: I don't need it to be real time, so I am hoping to keep my database writes to once a day.

Comment: To do what you're suggesting here, you're going to have to find each one of those records again in the database and update it's page count after you've counted the hits from the log. That's so much extra legwork! If your app is getting such high traffic that you can't afford a db write per page view, then you need to re-evaluate how you're approaching this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would change the logger to create different log files every day.  This way you can parse an entire log file without worrying about hitting the same line twice.  You can do that by adding this to your `production.rb` file:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths.log.first, 'daily')
```

Then, you can just write a little Ruby file that runs on a cron job shortly after midnight.  Here is an idea:

```
hits = Hash.new(0)
yesterday = Time.now - (24 * 60 * 60)
yesterday_formatted = yesterday.strftime("%Y%m%d") # 20110126
File.open("production.log.#{yesterday_formatted}", "r") do |infile|
  while (line = infile.gets)
    match = /(GET|POST) (\S+)/.match(line)
    hits[match[2]] += 1 if match
  end
end

hits.each do |page, count|
  # Record number of hits for this page in the database
end
```

However, I think that it would be easier to use Google Analytics or something.

Comment: I am using Analytics for more complex stats, but this should be perfect to sort the projects by popularity. - thanks!